# A way of saying "cognitive style" that emphasizes when it is neither a choice nor learned

Tags: phrase-requests

**EDIT:** There has been some confusion about this question. @alphabet1 in the comments got it: I'm asking for an alternative to the phrase "cognitive style" without the word "style." Something shorter than **"the cognitive differences in people with autism that come from underlying neurology as opposed to those which are learned."**

I am an adult recently diagnosed with autism and I am trying to refine how I explain autism to others. One important concept is that the differences in how we communicate interpersonally are not "behaviors." They result from a different "cognitive style."

However, the term "cognitive style" feels to me like it is something that can be learned and can be unlearned like a style of cooking, or taken on and off like a style of clothing. We process, structure, and prioritize information differently on a neurological level, which results in differences in interpersonal relationships and communication.

What would be a better word than *style*, or a different expression/phrase altogether than "cognitive style" in this application?

N.B. Short of calling it a "myth" about autism, the idea that autistic people have trouble with developing social norms but can learn them is outdated. Our challenges with social norms don't result from lagging skills[<sup>1</sup>](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6113117/) [<sup>2</sup>](https://www.thegrovepsychiatry.com/assessment-skills). In fact, autistic people feel very comfortable with the communication styles of other autistic people. See "double emplathy."[<sup>3</sup>](https://kids.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/frym.2021.554875) [<sup>4</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_empathy_problem#Double_empathy_and_bidirectional_communication_studies)

Comment: I sympathize, but some of us call it behavioral modification....and this is not the place to post this.

Comment: Are you asking about _neuro-divergent_?

Comment: Or "neurotype"?

Comment: One may say "way of thinking" to refer to *cognitive skills* or *cognitive logic*.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ This is very much within ELU's scope; it's about finding a word to use to describe something.

Comment: The problem here is that there is no common terminology for what you want to describe. Researchers may have technical language for it, but if you're trying to communicate with neurotypical people, there's nothing simple that they'd understand. You have to explain the whole thing.

Comment: Is the distinction that the style is "congential" (or perhaps "innate" or "inherent")? Those terms are commonly used to make clear that a trait is not acquired after birth, if that's what you mean.

Comment: https://dictionary.apa.org/cognitive-style

Comment: @StuartF -- thank you for posting that link. It exemplifies the ambiguity between what neurological vs. psychological in the phrase "cognitive style."

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes. That is what I mean. Saying _innate cognitive style_ might work for what I'm after. Also, in my comment to tinfoilhat's answer, _neurocognitive style_, _neurocognitive traits_, or perhaps with your suggestion, _innate cognitive traits_.

Answer (score 3):

[Neurodiversity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurodiversity) is not exactly a synonym for an individual's own particular "style", but it seems a bit better to be described as "neurodiverse" than "neurodivergent", which implies one has diverged from the norm. Same with neurotype, since it leads to "neurotypical" being the norm.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes described as being *wired differently*,<sup>*</sup> the concept also goes by the term *neurodivergent*:

> **neurodivergent**, *adj.* and *n.*
> **A.** *adj.*
>  Differing in mental or neurological functioning from what is considered typical or normal; esp. designating a person on the
> autism spectrum. Also: of or relating to such persons.
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

[An article at Forbes.com](https://www.forbes.com/health/mind/what-is-neurodivergent/) explains:

> Neurodivergent is a non-medical umbrella term that describes people
> with variation in their mental functions, and can include conditions
> such as autism spectrum disorder (ASD) or other neurological or
> developmental conditions such as attention-deficit/hyperactivity
> disorder (ADHD). . . .
>
> Neurodivergent individuals often experience
> differences in mental function, learning styles, sensory processing,
> communication styles and behaviors.

*Neurodivergent* is an adjective: *I am a neurodivergent person. I am neurodivergent*.

If you need a noun, you’re going to need to outpace the dictionaries with *neurodivergency*: *My neurodivergency allows me to prioritize information differently.*

---

<sub>*[*Wired Differently – 30 Neurodivergent People You Should Know* (Joe Wells, 2022)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1787758427)</sub>

Comment: I'm looking for a noun.

Comment: @abalter The **n.** in *adj. and n.* means it's a noun.

Comment: I gave you the noun: *neurodivergency*. @hippietrail — The noun referred to by the *OED* is as, e.g.: *The neurodivergent think differently.* *The rich eat caviar.*

Comment: Well yeah there's two nouns, one of which is also a verb.

Comment: @hippietrail — I don’t see a verb in either.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: Sorry that was a brainfart. Two nouns, one of which is also an adjective. Apologies again.

Comment: Yup. I think _neurodivergency_ is workable. I missed that. I would prefer something like "cognitive *" with a different word than style, to emphasize I'm talking about the cognitive aspects of _neurodivergency_ (as opposed to, say, sensory). Maybe I should be more explicit in my "ask".

Comment: @TinfoilHat If I said _neurocognitive style_ do you think this would clearly mean what I am after? Or maybe _neurocognitive traits_?

Comment: The word *style* has the same problem as in your original question. How about *neurocognitive function* or *neurocognitive functioning*?

Answer (score 0):

Tinfoil Hat's answer is close, but the specific word you're looking for is **neurotype.** This term is somewhat obscure but has [a Wiktionary entry:](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/neurotype)

> A type of brain, in terms of how a person interprets and responds to social cues, etc.
>
> Used mainly in discussions of autism.

It seems to be good enough for scientific studies. ["Neurotype-Matching, but Not Being Autistic, Influences Self and Observer Ratings of Interpersonal Rapport"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7645034/) provides one example:

> The Double Empathy Problem suggests that communicative difficulties between autistic and non-autistic people are due to bi-directional differences in communicative style and a reciprocal lack of understanding. If true, there should be increased similarity in interaction style, resulting in higher rapport during interactions between pairs of the same **neurotype.**